# Why does std::string return the tail of the string when adding an integer

Tags: c++, string

I understand you can not use `operator+` to concatenate an integer to a `std::string` without converting it to a `char*` or `std::string`.

But why does adding an integer returns the tail of a string?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string x;
    x = "hello world" + 3;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Prints: `lo world`

If you change: `x = "hello world" + 8;`

We print: `rld`

What's the reasoning behind this?  Undefined behavior?

Comment: ptr + int = other ptr

Comment: `"hello world"` is not a `std::string`, it's a `const char[12]`.

Comment: You could investigate less arbitrarily - `"hello world" + 0`, `"hello world" + 1`, `"hello world" + 2`, and so on. A pattern emerges quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to know your types. Firs of all, you are **not** adding 3 to the `std::string`. Addition happens before `std::string` is created. Instead you are adding 3 to the `char[12]`, which is defined, since char array decays to `char*`, and adding 3 to it advances the pointer  by 3 elements. This is exactly what you see.

Than `std::string` is constructed from the result, and you end up with a *tail*.

Answer (score 2):

It's equivalent to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string x;
    const char* p = "hello world";
    p = p + 3;
    x = p;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

You can make it safer this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std::literals;

int main()
{
    std::string x;
    x = "hello world"s + 3;      // error! won't compile
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know a string is an array of chars, if you put the `+ 3` you are stating you are going to take the string from the third position to the end of it

Answer (score 0):

```
int data[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int *dp = data;
std::cout << *(dp + 3) << '\n';
```

Now, here, `dp + 3` points at the 4 in the data array; that's just pointer arithmetic. So *(dp + 3) is 4, and that's what you see in the output stream.

Same thing with a `char*`: adding an integer to it gives you a new pointer value, offset from the original by the value of the integer:

```
char data[5] = "abcd";
char *dp = data;
std::cout << *(dp + 3) << '\n';
```

`dp` points at the beginning of the array, and `dp + 3` points at the letter 'd'. So *(dp + 3) is d, and that's what you see in the output.

You get the same thing when you use a pointer and an offset to initialize an object of type `std::string`: the pointer plus offset points at a location inside the char array, and the resulting `std::string` object holds a copy of the characters from that location out to the terminating null character.